# Can I use correlation metrics also for time series?

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

I was using the cross correlation function in R (`ccf`) until now to discover correlations and lags between two time series.

I was wondering if I can use all other correlation metrics for time series as well or are there any restrictions with time series? For example, I want to use Spearman's rank correlation coefficient to compare two ordinal scaled time series. Is that a valid approach and can I use it to detect lags as well? The same for nominal-scaled time series (events like on/off or status) like phi or Cramér's V?

Comment: In principle, other measures of correlation or association could be used for time series. In principle, a problem would be that dependence structure vitiates conventional significance tests. In practice, what you propose seems rarely done. It's hard to see that these other measures could point to useful models. Much of the point about autocorrelation and cross-correlation functions is that their properties can be deduced for various generating processes, although going the other way is more difficult and dangerous than some treatments imply.

Comment: i was doing some research about that topic before and didn't find lots of information about calculating correlations about ordinal or nominal scaled time series. But the ccf-function is not valid for that requirement I guess. Are there any specific metrics for ordinal and nominal scaled time series?

Comment: There is work on e.g. binary time series analysis. I am not familiar with the literature. Most time series texts I've seen focus entirely or predominantly on counted or measured responses.

Comment: So is CCF the only way to discover correlations between two nominal (or ordinal) scaled time series or are there any alternatives for that requirement? I am surprised that there is almost no information about that topic findable.

Comment: You **could** use the measures you name to quantify correlations. It's just unclear how that would help you model the time series. There is literature on e.g. Markov chains modelling transitions between states; it's just, so far as I can gather, in practice not closely tied to time series analysis, conventionally so called.

Comment: Let me give an example how I wanna use the measure, perhaps I am going into the wrong direction. A system sends me the current condition, which can be "very bad, bad, good, very good" and the timestamp. My goal is to find out if any of my variables like "temperature", etc. correlates with (or causes) that condition. Would there be a better approach than correlation metrics to discover that relationships? thanks

Comment: Plotting the data would be a start. No correlation can tell you what the relationship is; at best how strong it is in some sense.